# OrientDB: How are nodes and edges stored internally

Tags: orientdb

Quick question, but one that Google hasn't yielded any results for.

Whilst comparing different graph databases, I found [this useful slide](http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals) on the internals of Neo4j. I found slides 3-12 particularly interesting, as they explained how the graph (nodes/edges/properties) is represented/serialized on disk.

I'm now looking closely at OrientDB as my likely DB of choice. Can anyone with knowledge of OrientDB's architecture please describe the internal representation that it uses to store graph data, analogously to that on the slides linked above? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @DarkOwl, have you seen the doc https://orientdb.com/docs/2.1.x/Storages.html